# Write filename to first line of text

Tags: r, string

I have text files I'm manipulating with grep() and I'd like to add the file name to the first line of text. I'm new to R and stuck. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the content of your text files is supposed to be, but if there's a valid comment character for the file, I'd recommend putting that in front of the file name.  You can accomplish this with a combination of `readLines`, and `write`.

First, you'll want to read the content of the file with `readLines`.  Then you make a vector of the file name, and then the content from `readLines`.  Then you write the vector back to the file it came from.

Truthfully, it would be better to write it to a different file and not alter your source material, but I'll leave it to you to figure out how you want to manage that.  The code below uses temporary files for illustration

```
#* Create a temporary file
this_file <- tempfile("an_example_file", tmpdir = getwd(), fileext = ".txt")

#* Populate the file with some text
write(LETTERS, this_file)

#* Here's the real start of the solution
file_text <- readLines(this_file)

write(
  paste0(
    c(sprintf("## %s \n\n", this_file),
      file_text)
  ),
  this_file
)

#* see the changes
readLines(this_file)

#* cleanup
file.remove(this_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and for explaining the process. This is for biology sequence data and modifying the output of one program to be imported by another program. It's easy enough to name the files correctly when I generate them but a lot harder to manually edit them all with the correct first line text to be read by the other program later. There isn't a valid comment character for my file. You're right about not altering the source material but I was just going to place a bunch of copies in a different directory and modify them there.

Comment: @DanK You should make a list and then give the items in the list the names of the files. Don't go down the "SAS path" of thinking you need to write code that will be stripping lines from the files or having duplicate structures that you will manipulate with for loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename <- 'whatever.txt'
file.text <- readLines(filename)
file.text <- c(filename, file.text) # adds filename to beginning of file.text
fileConn<-file(filename)
writeLines(file.text, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

Comment: Thanks, it pastes the whole path but I can work with this.